# Server-side code is not working in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

i am added one button on user control it is working fine locally but not working on server my error is

> CS1061: 'ASP.templates_categories_productsingrid_ascx' does not contain a definition for 'dl_viewall' and no extension method 'dl_viewall' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.templates_categories_productsingrid_ascx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

If you are 100% sure you have deployed correct files (ascx, aspx and DLL's), try and recycle the app pool in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Web Application Project (and not a Website), make sure that you upload the updated dlls in the bin folder in the project to the server as well - these contain the code that the IIS server will run, not the .aspx.cs.